# Sqlite DB file read

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, firefox

I write Visual Basic programs as a hobby
I want to read the "places.sqlite" file in the portable version of Firefox. But when trying to read it
This message is coming.

'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

What is the solution to this?

Comment: How did you reference the SQLite library? It sounds like you might have an inappropriate version. You should add it as a NuGet package. That will ensure that you get the right version and also make updates easier.

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core? Note that .NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core?